# SSRS report to display Outlook type calendar - People x Days x Activities

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I am after a pattern/view/opinion/tip/weblink from an SSRS/SQL expert on how I might create a report that enables me to list something like the following:

[----Person----]  | [29-Sep-11] | [30-Sep-11] | [01-Oct-11] | [02-Oct-11]  | [03-Oct-11]... and so on...
Bob Bobertson  |    Activity A   |   Activity B    |    ----Empty---   |   Activity C   | ---Empty--- |
Rob Robertson  |   Activity D   |   Activity E   |    Activity F   |   Activity G  | ---Empty--- |
...and so on...

Date columns are dynamic - example, 10 days on from today (rolling window report)
Person column is dynamic list based on a user collection
So the above table looks pretty simple, but theres an extra dimension/depth to it.
I need to get the details for the Activity to create a link to it and style it in the report based on other flags.

I'm currently stumped on how to structure my resultset, and then how to Group/Pivot the data into a report structure.

Has anyone done similar before?

I'm using CRM4.0 for records including Date, Person, ActivityTitle, Billable etc

SSRS 2008 for the report building via VS2008 BI studio

Comment: I can't self answer for another 7 hours!?!? OK....

Turns out to be very simple!
You can just insert a tablix and chose the date field for the column headers, and the Username for the row labels.
Add a formula for the intersect to use more than one of the remaining values, and thats the three dimensions solved!

Comment: Think of the tablix (matrix) control as a "design time pivot table" and you can't go wrong

Answer (score 0):

Turns out to be very simple! You can just insert a tablix and chose the date field for the column headers, and the Username for the row labels. Add a formula for the intersect to use more than one of the remaining values, and thats the three dimensions solved! – BennIT

Adolf Garlic:
*Think of the tablix (matrix) control as a "design time pivot table" and you can't go wrong*
Many thanks for your input Adolf!

Comment: I would like to see the formula you used for the intersect. I'm trying something similar. I have a take of 'daily user registrations' with a date and a userID that I want to pivot.