# Fill cells depending of dataset values

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, report

I have a table like this one below. I have one dataset which returns data like this:

```
Day      Hour    Title
-----------------------
Monday   2       Title1
Monday   4       Title2
Friday   5       Title3
         .
         .
         .
         .
```

I need to fill the table depends of values in dataset, ie. first row of dataset will take place where first column(Monday) intersect with second row(2.).

How can I do this task.

I am using SSRS 2008.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

First, on database, I am creating two Common Table Expression or CTE, for days and hours respectively. Then, I am make CROSS JOIN between them, and thus form a one relation. Then I make left join with rest of needed tables, to get values (if exist, of course) for each combination from CROSS JOIN.

On reports, I am create matrix, related to dataset, which is linked with previously created stored procedure. For column group, I choose days, for row group I choose hours, on intersect I place specific values.

Really simple, but great job is done with cross joined two CTE's.

Answer (score 1):

Use a matrix.

[See here](http://ssrstutorials.blogspot.com/2012/10/lesson-15-ssrs-matrix-reports.html) also see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7600377/ssrs-report-to-display-outlook-type-calendar-people-x-days-x-activities)

EDIT: [This interesting blog post shows how you can build a calendar in SSRS.](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/reporting-services/ten-common-sql-server-reporting-services-challenges-and-solutions/#hr)